# Issues starting an Async Method from the OnCreate Overriden Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, xamarin

```
       Within OnCreate()
       new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
            this.RunOnUiThread(async () =>
            {
                await SetData(TodaysDate); ;
                //await FindNotesForDay(TodaysDate, TodaysDate.AddDays(+6));
                progress.Dismiss();
            });
        })).Start();



        private async Task SetData(DateTime date)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            dicMyMap = null;

            dicMyMap = new Dictionary<string, List<ClassInstance>>();

            List<string> group = new List<string>();

            group.Add("Monday");
            group.Add("Tuesday");
            group.Add("Wednesday");
            group.Add("Thursday");
            group.Add("Friday");

            dicMyMap.Add(group[0], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            date = date.AddDays(+1);

            dicMyMap.Add(group[1], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            date = date.AddDays(+1);

            dicMyMap.Add(group[2], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            date = date.AddDays(+1);

            dicMyMap.Add(group[3], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            date = date.AddDays(+1);

            dicMyMap.Add(group[4], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));


            myAdapater = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, group, dicMyMap);

            expandableListView.SetAdapter(myAdapater);
        });
    }

    private List<ClassInstance> ListsPopulation(String date)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM lectures join groupConvert using (Groups) where StartDate = '" + date + "' AND Cohort = '" + User.Cohort + "' AND Year = '" + User.IntakeYear + "';";

        List<ClassInstance> Temp = new List<ClassInstance>();

        //Insert Header
        Temp.Add(new ClassInstance("Start Time", "End   Time", "Subject", "Location", "", ""));

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, Connect.GetConnection()))
        {
             MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ClassInstance c = new ClassInstance(reader["StartTime"].ToString(), reader["EndTime"].ToString(), reader["Theme"].ToString(), reader["Location"].ToString(), reader["Essential"].ToString(), reader["Notes"].ToString());
                Temp.Add(c);
            }
        }

        if (Temp.Count == 1)
        {
            Temp.Clear();
            Temp.Add(new ClassInstance("No Classes", "", "", "", "", ""));
        }


        return Temp;
    }
```

Hello

I am currently attempting to populate a ListView from a database hosted on AWS. As you can imagine It takes a bit of time to load. My issue is my current code is throwing an error. The error thrown is ambiguous and not helpful just states the program has crashed.

In essence what i want to do is quite simple, I basically want to just display a dialog while these methods are loading.

Any advice regarding my code would be excellent.

Edit: I have narrowed the error message down to this area of the code. Prior to attempting to use threads I was able to load this Activity however due to the fact there wasn't a loading message it would appear to the user that the activity had frozen rather than the fact it was loading.

Thanks, 
Joe

Comment: If the error is ambiguous, how do you know the code you supplied is where the error occurs?  Have you tried adding exception handling where you suspect the error might be occurring and printing or logging the exception information?

Comment: What does `ListsPopulation` do? BTW, why are you mixing Tasks (new style) with ThreadStart (old style)? You are creating a thread in a thread and you don't await the result. That is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I will amend my question to include the additional content requested

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to fix the code above to run correctly.

If you have any feedback or comments let me know and i hope someone finds this helpful.

I was using the Async methods completely incorrectly, you are also unable to call a Async method from the oncreate as i'm sure you are aware. Part of my solution was to change all the methods which i had made Async incorrectly back to void (Meaning they were synchronous).

I then created a thread to run the commands and they are now finally running in the correct order :).

Its important to note within the Thread any elements affected by the UI will required them to be run using the main UI thread, this applies to the methods they called as well.

Below is the area of code which i created to fix the issue i had

```
    // Try catch attempt to catch all errors, the error dialog thrown within 
    //the catch is fairly simple 
    try
        {
            //Start loading spinner
            var LoadingProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading", "Loading", false);

            //Start loading thread, this thread will carry out the functions 
            // in the order you requested
            Thread LoadingThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                //Line below only relevant to my code
                StartMonday.Text = "Week Commencing On " + TodaysDate.ToLongDateString();
                // Call this method first
                SetData(TodaysDate);
                // call this method second
                FindNotesForWeek(TodaysDate, 7);
                //Update the UI on the main thread but call third this will close the loading dialog message
                RunOnUiThread(() => LoadingProgressDialog.Hide());
            // End of thread
            });
            //Run the thread
            LoadingThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var ErrorMessageDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading", e.ToString(), false);
        }
```

Below is my complete class for reference for another user. I have not doced this code as its large enough within this comment

```
        namespace MedicalHubApplication
        {
        [Activity(Label = "TimeTable", NoHistory = true)]
        public class TimeTable : Activity
        {
       ClassInstance populateClass = new ClassInstance();
       UserInstance User = new UserInstance();
       GetConnectionClass Connect = new GetConnectionClass();
       Dictionary<string, List<ClassInstance>> dicMyMap;

    TextView DateHeaderTV;
    TextView NoteHeaderTV;

    ExpandableListViewAdapter myAdapater;
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    // Need Instance of List 
    NotesListViewAdapter myNoteAdapater;
    ListView NotesListView;
    ScrollView ScrollViewList;

    TextView StartMonday;
    Button SelectDateButton;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TimeTable);

        expandableListView = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.ListViewExpanded);
        StartMonday = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextViewStartDateMonday);
        SelectDateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.SelectDateButton);
        NotesListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.NotesListView);
        DateHeaderTV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DateHeader);
        NoteHeaderTV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.NoteHeader);
        ScrollViewList = FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.ScrollView);

        // Populate User 
        User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInstance>(Intent.GetStringExtra("User"));

        //Find Monday 
        DateTime TodaysDate = DateTime.Now;
        while (TodaysDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) TodaysDate = TodaysDate.AddDays(-1);

        try
        {
            var LoadingProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading", "Loading", false);

            Thread LoadingThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                StartMonday.Text = "Week Commencing On " + TodaysDate.ToLongDateString();
                SetData(TodaysDate);
                FindNotesForWeek(TodaysDate, 7);
                RunOnUiThread(() => LoadingProgressDialog.Hide());

            });

            LoadingThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var ErrorMessageDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading", e.ToString(), false);
        }

        SelectDateButton.Click += delegate
        {
            DateSelectOnClick();  
        }; 
    }

    private void DateSelectOnClick()
    {
        DatePickerFragment frag = DatePickerFragment.NewInstance(delegate (DateTime SelectedDate)
        {
            while (SelectedDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) SelectedDate = SelectedDate.AddDays(-1);

            try
            {
                var LoadingProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading", "Loading", false);

                Thread LoadingThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(() => StartMonday.Text = "Week Commencing On " + SelectedDate.ToLongDateString());
                    SetData(SelectedDate);
                    FindNotesForWeek(SelectedDate, 7);
                    RunOnUiThread(() => LoadingProgressDialog.Hide());

                });

                LoadingThread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var ErrorMessageDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Loading", e.ToString(), false);
            }
        });
        frag.Show(FragmentManager, DatePickerFragment.TAG);
    }

    private void SetData(DateTime date)
    {

        dicMyMap = null;

        dicMyMap = new Dictionary<string, List<ClassInstance>>();

        List<string> group = new List<string>();

        group.Add("Monday");
        group.Add("Tuesday");
        group.Add("Wednesday");
        group.Add("Thursday");
        group.Add("Friday");

        dicMyMap.Add(group[0], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        date = date.AddDays(+1);

        dicMyMap.Add(group[1], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        date = date.AddDays(+1);

        dicMyMap.Add(group[2], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        date = date.AddDays(+1);

        dicMyMap.Add(group[3], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        date = date.AddDays(+1);

        dicMyMap.Add(group[4], ListsPopulation(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));


        myAdapater = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, group, dicMyMap);

        RunOnUiThread(() => expandableListView.SetAdapter(myAdapater));

    }

    private List<ClassInstance> ListsPopulation(String date)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM lectures join groupConvert using (Groups) where StartDate = '" + date + "' AND Cohort = '" + User.Cohort + "' AND Year = '" + User.IntakeYear + "';";

        List<ClassInstance> Temp = new List<ClassInstance>();

        //Insert Header
        Temp.Add(new ClassInstance("Start Time", "End   Time", "Subject", "Location", "", ""));

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, Connect.GetConnection()))
        {
             MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ClassInstance c = new ClassInstance(reader["StartTime"].ToString(), reader["EndTime"].ToString(), reader["Theme"].ToString(), reader["Location"].ToString(), reader["Essential"].ToString(), reader["Notes"].ToString());
                Temp.Add(c);
            }
        }

        if (Temp.Count == 1)
        {
            Temp.Clear();
            Temp.Add(new ClassInstance("No Classes", "", "", "", "", ""));
        }


        return Temp;
    }

    private void FindNotesForWeek(DateTime StartDate, int DaysInMonth)
    {
        List<NotesInstance> WeekNotes = new List<NotesInstance>();

        WeekNotes.AddRange(FindNotesForDay(StartDate, StartDate.AddDays(+DaysInMonth)));

        if (WeekNotes.Count != 0)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => NoteHeaderTV.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible);
            RunOnUiThread(() => NotesListView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible);
            RunOnUiThread(() => DateHeaderTV.Text = "Date:");

            myNoteAdapater = new NotesListViewAdapter(this, WeekNotes);

            RunOnUiThread(() => NotesListView.Adapter = myNoteAdapater);
        }
        else
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() => NoteHeaderTV.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible);
            RunOnUiThread(() => NotesListView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible);
            RunOnUiThread(() => DateHeaderTV.Text = "No Notifications");
        }

        // Set up Adapter 
        myNoteAdapater = new NotesListViewAdapter(this, WeekNotes);

        RunOnUiThread(() => NotesListView.Adapter = myNoteAdapater);
    }

    private List<NotesInstance> FindNotesForDay(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT *  FROM Notes WHERE dates between '" + StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND yearGroup = '" + User.IntakeYear.ToString() + "';";

        List<NotesInstance> Temp = new List<NotesInstance>();

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, Connect.GetConnection()))
        {

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                NotesInstance c = new NotesInstance(reader.GetDateTime("dates").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), reader["Notes"].ToString());
                Temp.Add(c);
            }
        }

        return Temp;
    }
}
```

}